# oci_error empty

Tags: php, oracle, error-handling

I'm trying to analyze the why my sql is failing, but my `oci_error` is empty. Not sure what's wrong, is there any setting I missed while installing OCI8?

here's my code:

```
    $group_list = oci_parse($dbc, "SELECT gn FROM groups");
    if (!$group_list) {
        $m = oci_error($group_list);
        print_r($m);
        echo "Query failed: " . $m['message'] . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "Query OK\n";
    }
```

The output says `Query failed:` but no error message, no text is printed.

Please help!!

EDIT:

This query is failing only when I write this block in a PHP function, otherwise the query runs successfully. Not sure why it is behaving like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a stupid question I guess.. `$dbc`, my connection handle, should be declared as global in my function. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Give oci_error the connection $dbc and not the statement $group_list. Also oci_execute($group_list) is missing.